# how to open file dialog gallery in a web Asp.net MVC application in with apple browser?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, ios5, safari

I have an Asp.net MVC Web application which has to run on all web browsers(IE, Firefox, Chrome) , even with Ipad & Android . I have a file dialog where I upload image.

The file dialog is disabled when I see it in browser of Apple devices like Ipad, Iphone etc. But this functionality works fine for other browsers.

Is there a way to enable file dialog or hack the Apple environment to open it's Library/Gallery? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari for iOS 5 does not support file uploading.  This is why it is disabled.  It's because iOS 5 doesn't really have a concept of a file system from which you can choose files.

iOS 6 has added support.  So your file uploads will only work with iOS 6 and later.

Comment: Thanx mate.I tested my scenario in IOS 6 & to my surprise it worked.The problem is with IOS 5 only.